# Increasing Heap Size in HazelCast

Tags: hazelcast

I am using the community version of HazelCast 3.2.1. I am trying to put 300,000 objects in HazelCast instance. In between the execution I see that HazelCast says that there is a total of 510 MB of Heap Size it is using and then also shows up the usage. I was wondering if there is a way to increase this Heap Size so that I should be able to store 300,000 objects in HazelCast Memory.

Thanks,

Praveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you would increase the heap size on every Java application, using commandline parameters -Xmx and -Xms.